# Injecting a reference bean from jar file, No bean named *** is defined exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

```
<bean id="org.sakaiproject.vidyayug.tool.SakaiStyleSelectorInterceptor" 
class="org.sakaiproject.vidyayug.tool.SakaiStyleSelectorInterceptor"> 
<property name="worksiteManager"> 
<ref bean="org.sakaiproject.metaobj.worksite.mgt.WorksiteManager"/> 
</property> 
</bean>
```

I am injecting ref bean from a jar file..
Exception is:

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.sakaiproject.metaobj.worksite.mgt.WorksiteManager' while setting bean property 'worksiteManager'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.sakaiproject.metaobj.worksite.mgt.WorksiteManager' is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a

```
<bean id="org.sakaiproject.metaobj.worksite.mgt.WorksiteManager" class="org.sakaiproject.metaobj.worksite.mgt.WorksiteManager"/>
```

in your application context.

Bean id and class name are not the same thing, even if you're giving them the same value.

The bean id should be a "handy" name you use to refer to a bean isntance, while the class is the actual fully qualified class name to load the bean from the classpath (jar or your class folder or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

do like that, give a bean id, and then call the reference by calling that id.

```
  <bean id="Order" class="com.classes.OrderPizza">
    <property name="pizzaTemp" ref="ChickenPizza"></property>
  </bean>

<bean id="ChickenPizza" class="com.classes.ChickenPizza"></bean>
<bean id="PaneerPizza" class="com.classes.PaneerPizza"></bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing a bean without instantiating it. Correct your code this way:

```
<bean id="org.sakaiproject.vidyayug.tool.SakaiStyleSelectorInterceptor" class="org.sakaiproject.vidyayug.tool.SakaiStyleSelectorInterceptor"> 
    <property name="worksiteManager"> 
        <bean class="org.sakaiproject.metaobj.worksite.mgt.WorksiteManager"/> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```

**NOTE** You also have to be sure the `jar` is deployed in your project binaries.